# Adding Data to MySQL Table using PHP(Revised)

Tags: php, mysql, forms

The code below is what I am using to add to tables already created in a database. I'm still receiving an error with the query, Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Location, Horseshoe) VALUES('Obed & Isaacs','Springfield Illinois','Buffalo Chic' at line 1.

How do I fix this error? It seems to be the only thing stopping the rest of the page to load.

```
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("*************","************","***********");
if (!$link)
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
}
mysql_error();
mysql_select_db(horseshoevotes); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `submissions` (Restaurant, Restaurant Location, Horseshoe)
VALUES('$_POST[restaurant]','$_POST[location]','$_POST[horseshoe]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error($link));
}
echo "Submitted";

mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Did you really just post your database credentials?

Comment: I have removed them. Hopefully they were placeholders, if not, Nathan should change the details on his server as soon as possible.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql methods. They have been deprecated. Use PDO or Mysqli

Comment: The database credentials were posted, I'm not worried as this is a test database, I had learned HTML early on, not thinking I would need anything else. How naive right? This stuff is just learning servers and what not.

Comment: just add mysql_error() function to see the error. you don't even display the error. who knows what error you have. we can't guest unless you find the error

Comment: If column names really do contain spaces (a really bad idea) then they need to be enclosed in backticks (`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't actually done anything to the database - you've only put the query into a variable.

Add

```
mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error! ".mysql_error());
```

before you call `mysql_close`.

Comment: I've had that in there prior. I re-added it, and am still getting nothing inserted into the table or database.

Comment: Do you have any error handling? Try echoing `$sql` and seeing what it says - maybe run it directly on the database to see if it works there?

Comment: See my edit - what happens if you put the error handling in your code?

Comment: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /hermes/waloraweb013/b1311/moo.enhstudios/enhstudios/enhtv/horseshoesubmission.php on line 21
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Location, Horseshoe, Email) VALUES('Obed & Isaacs','Spr' at line 2

Comment: I've fixed the bottom part of that. I'm still getting the Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resorce in... on line 21 Error

Comment: Lines 21-25:

if (!mysql_query($link,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error($link));
 }
echo "Submitted";

Comment: Use `mysql_query($sql, $link)` - your arguments are the wrong way around. You really should have posted all your code - we could have told you that in seconds.

Comment: See, doesn't matter I'm getting this error:

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Location, Horseshoe) VALUES('Obed & Isaacs','Springfield Illinois','Buffalo Chic' at line 1

I've updated my question with updated code

Answer (score 0):

Use like this instead of `$sql`

```
$restaurant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[restaurant]);
$location   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[location]);
$horseshoe  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[horseshoe]);
$email      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email]);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `submissions` 
                         (Restaurant, Location, Horseshoe, Email)
                         VALUES('$restaurant','$location','$horseshoe','$email')
           ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To learn quickly how to use MySQL, start using a wrapper class.

I recommend: https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Have used this myself when I first switched from MySQL to `MySQLi`. Made the learning curve lots smaller.

Have a look at the source (it's hosted on GitHub so you don't need to download it to have a glance).

Also do not continue to use MySQL. The successor **[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** is more secure due to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and some other improvements. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would be even better, but it's more advanced.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
`
```

around column names, that is this:

```
INSERT INTO `submissions` (Restaurant, Restaurant Location, Horseshoe)
```

should be this:

```
INSERT INTO `submissions` (`Restaurant`, `Restaurant Location`, `Horseshoe`)
```

I'm guessing the next thing you will see is the error about column count not matching with values. Please proof read and dry run your queries.